# How to get this "text disappearing" effect on span?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I have this span element: `<span id='title'>SOME TEXT HERE</span>`, with this CSS:

```
color: #fff;
line-height: 22px;
font-size: 16px;
float: left;
max-width: 320px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

I'm trying to achieve this "disappearing" effect on text. I played with `:after` but without success...

[image]

Comment: it's not good to spoil us with this Marvel information -.-

Comment: The suggested answer doesn't actually use `:after`
```
#title {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* determines point at which to start fade */
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, black 80%, black 80%));
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
``` should work on a black background

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```css
.fade-out {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.fade-out:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<span class='fade-out'>Spiderman Will Appear In Another MCU Movie Later Next Year</span>
```

Hope this helps,